# Record Audio Whilst Device is Locked iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

Does anyone know of an effective way to record audio whilst the device is locked on iOS?

Currently I am using two AVAudioRecorders, one to listen out for noises (audioListener) and one to actually record those noises (audioRecorder). The audioListener is always recording and getting the meter levels of the noises as it needs to be recording in order to get those levels. If those noises go above a threshold then the audioRecorder starts recording for five seconds and in the audioRecorderDidFinishRecording method will add each audio file to an array for reference later. I have also already set the "Application does not run in background" key in the info.plist to NO and allowed the audio background mode.

I still need to do a few more tests to see if it records correctly when the device is locked but was wondering anyone knew of any other ways of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the audio category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` as well as the background audio mode as you have done.

Check out the [AudioSession Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html)

Comment: I have already done that, it may be something to do with not saving the audio files correctly.

Comment: Thats a different question

Comment: I understand that, I just meant it may not be the audio recording thats the issue but rather how I'm saving the data. Do you have any idea if I could use this method to record over a few hours whilst the device is locked?

Comment: Have you tested it? I would use something more low-level like Core-Audio with ExtAudioFileWriteAsync. Just pass the buffer you get from the microphone callback to the ExtAudioFileWriteAsync function. Limit the Objective-C or Swift calls in the callback, preferably use C or C++.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. The issue with doing it the way I was before I'm relying on a timer to call the method which checks if the noises are above a certain volume. I would assume this timer would get paused when the device is locked. I will need to look into your way of doing it with Core Audio.

Comment: Yeah, that will also drain battery power. With CoreAudio you get buffers of data passed ti your callback function which you can then process. Inside this function you can check for the db levels or frequency etc.